# pyspark dataframe filter or include based on list

Tags: apache-spark, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a dataframe in pyspark using a list.  I want to either filter based on the list or include only those records with a value in the list.  My code below does not work:

```
# define a dataframe
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"])

# define a list of scores
l = [10,18,20]

# filter out records by scores by list l
records = df.filter(df.score in l)
# expected: (0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2)

# include only records with these scores in list l
records = df.where(df.score in l)
# expected: (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)
```

Gives the following error:
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Answer (score 170):

what it says is "df.score in l" can not be evaluated because df.score gives you a column and "in" is not defined on that column type use "isin"

The code should be like this:

```
# define a dataframe
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "score"])

# define a list of scores
l = [10,18,20]

# filter out records by scores by list l
records = df.filter(~df.score.isin(l))
# expected: (0,1), (0,1), (0,2), (1,2)

# include only records with these scores in list l
df.filter(df.score.isin(l))
# expected: (1,10), (1,20), (3,18), (3,18), (3,18)
```

Note that [`where()` is an alias for `filter()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where), so both are interchangeable.

Comment: How would you do this with a broadcast variable as a list instead of a regular python list? I'm getting a 'Broadcast' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' error when I try and do it that way.

Comment: @flyingmeatball I think you can broadcast_variable_name.value to access the list

Comment: If you want to use broadcasting then the this is the way to go: `l_bc = sc.broadcast(l)` followed by `df.where(df.score.isin(l_bc.value))`

Comment: If you are trying to filter the dataframe based on a list of column values, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66228314/530399

Answer (score 64):

based on @user3133475 answer, it is also possible to call the [`isin()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html) function from `col()` like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


l = [10,18,20]
df.filter(col("score").isin(l))
```

Answer (score 13):

I found the `join` implementation to be significantly faster than `where` for large dataframes:

```
def filter_spark_dataframe_by_list(df, column_name, filter_list):
    """ Returns subset of df where df[column_name] is in filter_list """
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    filter_df = spark.createDataFrame(filter_list, df.schema[column_name].dataType)
    return df.join(filter_df, df[column_name] == filter_df["value"])
```

Comment: why is that so? you have to shuffle tons of data with this?