# How to filter column on values in list in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe rawdata on which i have to apply filter condition on column X with values CB,CI and CR. So I used the below code:

```
df = dfRawData.filter(col("X").between("CB","CI","CR"))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> between() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541958/3712254. I found the `join` implementation to be faster than `where`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The function `between` is used to check if the value is between two values, the input is a lower bound and an upper bound. It can not be used to check if a column value is in a list. To do that, use `isin`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = dfRawData.where(f.col("X").isin(["CB", "CI", "CR"]))
```

Comment: Extending on @Shaido's answer. If you want to negate the statement you can use the `~` sign like so:  `df = dfRawData.where(~f.col("X").isin(["CB", "CI", "CR"]))`