# How to filter dataframe to get rows which have column value IN a user-defined set

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to get all rows which DO NOT have a value of the `"previous_page_path"` column in the set `("forbidden_val_1", "forbidden_val_2")`. I've tried this:

```
dfRefUrl.filter(dfRefUrl["previous_page_path"] in ("forbidden_val_1", "forbidden_val_2"))
```

but it crashes my program. Is there any way to do this kind of filtering?

Comment: use `dfRefUrl["previous_page_path"].isin(("forbidden_val_1", "forbidden_val_2"))` .. looking for the right dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a Pyspark DataFrame with SQL-like IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870760/filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-sql-like-in-clause) and [pyspark dataframe filter or include based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list) and [How to filter column on values in list in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707339/how-to-filter-column-on-values-in-list-in-pyspark?rq=1)