# pyspark - Run a spark sql query in parallel for multiple ids in a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a list, let's say

```
ids = ['K50', 'K51', 'K51', 'P41', 'P41', 'P42']
```

What I need to achieve -

1. Take each id from the list
2. Get data from a hive table (eg. tableA ) for each site.
3. Pivot some values for that data.
4. Write to a parquet file for each id.

Note - I need to run this job in parallel for each id in the list.

I have looked at several posts but did not find any concrete solution. How can I solve this problem in pyspark?

Spark Version - 2.4.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark dataframe filter or include based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repartion the data based on the key. I had implemented this using distribute-key and cluster-by. Check the below url. U will find lot of blogs on this topic.

```
https://deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/
```

Comment: I need multiple sql queries to run in parallel for that list. I assume, distribute by or repartition won't help here.