# How do I write an equivalent pyspark code for the following staement?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
    X_train[var] = np.where(X_train[var].isin(frequent_ls), X_train[var], 'Rare')
```

How can I replace numpy with pyspark sql function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark dataframe filter or include based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define an udf function

```
from spark.sql import function as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType()

def dictonnary(x):
    if x in frequent_ls: 
        return x 
    else:
        return "rare"

replace = F.udf(lambda x: dictionnary(x), StrungType())

Xtrain = xtrain.withColumn("var2", replace(F.col("var")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the .[`isin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) operator:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

X_train = (X_train
           .withColumn(var, F.when(X_train[var].isin(frequent_ls), X_train[var]).otherwise('Rare'))
```