# Pyspark: Convert sql query to pyspark?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have **two set of queries with some case statements**. I need to convert the same logic in pyspark.

```
**First query**
case
when appointment_date is null
then 0
--Ticket resolved without having to send a truck out
when nvl(resolution,'') in (
'CSTXCL - OK BY PHONE'
,'OK AT TIME CALLED'
,'CONFIRMED OK BY PHONE'
,'RESOLVED THROUGH FOLLOW UP'
,'OK BY PHONE CALL'
)
or nvl(resolution,'') ilike '%NO VAN ROLL%'
then 0
when wo_status in ('PENDING','CANCELLED')
then 0
when stype = 'install'
and (
btrim(job_task,'\"') ilike '%Disco%'
or btrim(job_task,'\"') ilike '%Reconnect%'
or btrim(job_task,'\"') ilike '%Wireless Uninstall%'
or btrim(job_task,'\"') ilike '%Remove%'
or btrim(job_task,'\"') ilike '%Retrieve%'
)
and btrim(job_task,'\"') not ilike '%[!n]Install%'
and btrim(job_task,'\"') not ilike '%[!se]Connect%'
and btrim(job_task,'\"') not ilike 'Install%'
and btrim(job_task,'\"') not ilike '%(COPPER TO FTTH)%'
then 0
else 1
end as truck_roll
```

```
**Second query**

case when wo_status = 'COMPLETED'  and nvl(resolution,'') not in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO')
then 1 else 0 end as completed, --these resolutions indicate cancelled tickets, so even if they come in as closed, call it cancelled
case when wo_status = 'CREATED' then 1 else 0 end as created,
case when wo_status = 'PENDING'  and nvl(resolution,'') not in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO') then 1 else 0 end as pending,
case when wo_status = 'CANCELLED'  or ( wo_status in ('COMPLETED','PENDING' ) and nvl(resolution,'') in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO') ) then 1 else 0 end as cancelled.
```

If anyone knows how to achieve the same logic in pyspark that would be appreciated.

I tried till this for first set of query.

```
df.withColumn('truck_roll', when(df.appointment_date.isNull(), 0).when(df.nvl(resolution,'').isin('CSTXCL - OK BY PHONE','OK AT TIME CALLED','CONFIRMED OK BY PHONE','RESOLVED THROUGH FOLLOW UP','OK BY PHONE CALL')
      |(df.nvl(resolution,'')like(''%NO VAN ROLL%''),0))
```

after this I was stucked.  I need to have case with btrim. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) When asking questions, it's adviced to create a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to simplify for people answering your question. See my anser below, I've simplified your code to contain a minimal example of the problem you are facing without unneccesary code.

Comment: I've given an answer (see answer below) to how to achieve a `case`-statement in pyspark which I understood was your question. If you have more detailed question I suggest you create seperate questions, for example one for how to achieve `case`-statements, one on how to achieve `and`/`or` et.c. (assuming you do not find any similair questions). If you still have issues, please provide the pyspark-code you have tried (again, minimal reproducable) and why it does not work and I can have a look :).

Comment: @Cleared Thanks for your response. I want an example for this scenario(not in):      case when wo_status = 'COMPLETED'  and nvl(resolution,'') not in ('CANCELLING ORDER','CANCEL ORDER','CLOSE SRO')
then 1 else 0 end as completed

Comment: How can I handle this..Can you pls help

Comment: Do this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421845/pyspark-dataframe-filter-or-include-based-on-list?

Comment: Pleasae update your question with the pyspark-code you've tried and why it does not work (it's hard to read code from comments).

Comment: Please check the updated question above @Cleared

Comment: Please format your code (and reduce the amount of it) before posting - it is hard on the eyes to look at your question let alone read it.

Comment: Im sorry, I really think you should create a new and clear question regarding `btrim` in pyspark and how to achieve this. Do a minimal example-code containing ONLY the `btrim`-functionality, search on Google and here at SO to see if you can find any answer or possible solutions. Then try those solutions, include what you have tried in your code and explain why it does not work. This question is getting out of hand.

Comment: Okay sure, Thanks much for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `when`-function (see [pyspark.sql.functions.when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html))

So, to simplify your query a bit:

```
case
    when job_task is null then 0
    when job_task = 'ABC' then 1
    else 2
end as truck_roll
```

Would be translated into the following in `pyspark`

```
df.withColumn(
    'truck_roll',
    when(df.job_task.isNull(), 0)
    .when(df.job_task == 'ABC', 1)
   .otherwise(2)
)
```

I.e. you can nest `when` as above to have multiple "cases", and instead of `else` you use `otherwise`.

Comment: I formatted your answer so it will be readable (and corrected the missing ")").